# Is it possible to make glass in Minecraft glow?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm making a modern house in my Minecraft world and I'm making led lights using colored glass and using torches to light them, but it's hard to cover up the torches on the inside of the house. Is it possible to make the glass glow its color with command blocks, cheats, etc.
Thanks.

Comment: Well, you could possibly use the 'Glow' potion effect on a command spawned Shulker that is inside the glass block, but that doesn't seem like the glow effect you are looking for

Comment: Primarily, Minecraft doesn't support colored light. So nothing glows 'its color'.

Answer (score 2):

## No, it's impossible.

But, if your lights are on the floor, you could always cover them up with Carpet.

---

A technical thing you can do (but this is for Java Edition) is to manually edit the light data around the places you want to be lit. However, the moment something updates light (like breaking a block), that will be lost.

Answer (score 0):

There are unfortunately no mods like that for Windows 10 edition of Minecraft listed on minecrafthub.com/mods/windows+10. If you are on Java, then there are more options available to you